# Why is flexWrap not working in React Native?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I'm new to this, so it would be great if someone could point me out in the right direction. I'm attaching a piece of code, it belongs to a component I'm trying to create that SHOULD display a sentence where the user can fill out the blank spaces. In this instance, the blank spaces in the sentence are passed as *. I break the sentence into (sub)sentences and then put the textInput after each one of them except for the last one, which I add at the end. Here is the code:

```js
 else {
        //fill out the blanks
        questionText = questionText.split("*");
        let lastPiece = questionText.pop();
        return (
            <View style={styles.question}>
                <Text style={{marginBottom:"20px"}} h4>Fill out the blank spaces:</Text>
                <View style={styles.sentence}>
                    {questionText.map((piece) => {
                        return (
                            <View style={styles.subsentence}>
                                {piece.split(' ').map((word) => {
                                    return (<Text>{word} </Text>)
                                })}
                                <TextInput placeholderTextColor="white" style={styles.blank} />
                            </View>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                    <View style={styles.subsentence}>
                        {lastPiece.split(' ').map((word) => {
                            return (<Text>{word} </Text>)
                        })}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Question;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    question: {
        marginTop:"20px",
        marginRight:"30px",
        marginLeft:"30px"
    },
    blank: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    sentence:{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    subsentence: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap:'wrap'
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason the elements won't wrap, I've tried different things but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?